# How to get specific value or row data from firebase in web

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

basically I new to firebase, I just want to that how to retrive specific data from firebase ,
[firabase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vk0S6.png[1]

as you can see in above image I want to retrieve like in Sql we use 
`Select CellNum from Student where Email="Adnan@gmail.com`.
How can I do that in firebase web javascript?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.   Could you include the (formatted) code you have tried so far?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40471284/firebase-search-by-child-value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following:

```
firebase.database().ref().child("Students").orderByChild("Email").equalTo("Adnan@gmail.com").once("value", function (snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
    var cellNum=childSnapshot.val().CellNum;
  });
});
```

The snapshot is at `Students`, then you loop inside the id `22222` and retrieve the `CellNum`. The `orderByChild` is the query `where Email="Adnan@gmail.com"`

Comment: yeah this works , thanks