# Filter firebase records by the array value of a specific property

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-functions

I am playing around with [firebase functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) and I have a question. The structure of my firebase DB is as follows:

```
 myDb
  |
Users
    |
    000001
      |
      Name: Sam
      |
      Items: [1,2,3]
    |
    000002
      |
      Name: Jim
      |
      Items: [3,4,5]
```

And what I want to do is to filter all of the users which have **3** inside of their *Items* value. I didn't find anything similar to: [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40471284/firebase-search-by-child-value) on their documentations for filtering data. Maybe because it is not a simple value. I don't know. I am now wondering how to perform this particular filtering.

Comment: How do you store the array? Is the index of the element the key property: `items: { 0: 1, 1: 2, 2:3 }`

Answer (score 3):

Array contain filters aren't possible in Firebase Realtime Database but it is a recent addition to [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership).

```
firebase.firestore().collection('users').where('items', 'array-contains', 3)
```

In the Firebase Realtime Database you would want to structure them as an object which you could query on

```
{
    name: "Jim",
    items: {
        1: true,
        2: true,
        3: true
    }
}
```

and then the query would be like this

```
firebase.database().ref('users').orderByChild('items/3').equalTo(true);
```

Comment: Would it be possible to have the keys as strings (e.g. {"str1":1, "str2":2}) and then to have .orderByChild('items/str1').equalTo(1); ?